# Отображается неверная длительность

Tags: ffmpeg

При конвертации ffmpeg (старой версией уже не вспомню какой) проблем с аудио не было. После перехода на HTML5 плеер длительность аудио вместо 11 секунд стало показывать 1:48, но проигрывается так же 11 секунд. Интересно то, что реконвертирование с новой версией ffmpeg таких фейковых длительностей не было. Попробовал просто воспроизвести трек на аудио плеере(трек взят тот, который в HTML5 проигрователе показывал длительность 1:48). И вот что получилось:
[image: Проигрование плеером]

Как видно из рисунка в плей листе показывает фейковую длительность, но длительность самой дорожки 0:11.

Так же показало и в vlc player (если 2 дорожки в плей листе и основная дорожка не проигрывалась, то длительность была фейковой, но после того, как началось воспроизведение требуемой дорожки в плей листе моментом длительность поменялась с фейковой на нормальную), но в Windows MP всё в норме.

По какому принципу в плей листе тоже отобразилась фейковая длительность. Может плеер расчитывает налету длительность исходя из инфы в заголовках?